# conflict type error previous declaration ___ was here

Tags: c

```
#define TRIP 6
#include <stdio.h>

char error_area(char area_code, char S, char M, char L, char N, char P, char K, char R, char C, char U, char W, char O, char T, char F);

int main(void)
{
  char area_code, S, M, L, N, P, K, R, C, U, W, O, T, F, checkB, travelarea[TRIP];

  printf("Please select from the following that best describes your destination:\n");   /*area code input*/
  printf("S Small city - population under 50,000\n");                                   /*Choices for area code*/ 
  printf("M Medium city - population between 50,000 and 500,000\n");
  printf("L Large city - pop. over 500,000\n");
  printf("N Natural formation like a mountain, a lake, a cave, a geyser, a fjord, a canyon, etc.\n");
  printf("P Designated park or reserve such as a wildlife refuge, a national park, a bioreserve, or a protected marine area\n");
  printf("K Man made landmark like the Great Wall of China, the Taj Mahal, or Stonehenge\n");
  printf("R State or province or region of a country\n");
  printf("C Whole country\n");
  printf("U Multiple countries like traveling through Europe\n");
  printf("W Ocean voyage\n");
  printf("O Any other type of destination - such as visiting the sites of the seven wonders of the world\n");
  printf("Please enter the Area Letter code:");
  scanf("%c", &area_code);   

  checkB = error_area(area_code, S, M, L, N, P, K, R, C, U, W, O, T, F);
  while (checkB == F)                              /*error loop for error area code*/
    {
      printf("Please re-enter a valid area_code:");
      scanf("%c", &area_code);
      checkB = error_area(area_code, S, M, L, N, P, K, R, C, U, W, O, T, F);
      if (checkB == T)
    {travelarea[0]=area_code;}
    } 

}    

error_area(area_code, S, M, L, N, P, K, R, C, U, W, O, T, F)   /*area code error check*/
{

  if ( (area_code == S) || (area_code == M) || (area_code == L) ||(area_code == N) ||(area_code == P) ||(area_code == K) || (area_code == R) ||(area_code == C) || (area_code == U) || (area_code == W) || (area_code == O))
    {
      return T;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Area code is invalid. (Please make sure code is capitalize)\n");

      return F ;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
test2.c:40: error: conflicting types for âerror_areaâ
test2.c:5: error: previous declaration of âerror_areaâ was here
```

I keep getting these error messages when I compile and I'm sure I declared the prototype and its type at the beginning so I'm not sure why there a conflict in types.
One of my tutors told me that it was because it was declared and to define all the types at the bottom where I called error_area but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you declared the prototype for `error_area` function does not mean that you are now free to omit return type and parameter types in the *definition*. When you *define* your `error_area` you are still supposed to specify all types explicitly

```
char error_area(char area_code, char S, char M, char L, char N, char P, char K, char R, char C, char U, char W, char O, char T, char F)
{
  ...
```

Instead, you defined your `error_area` without the explicit type names. The definition was interpreted in accordance with the "old" rules, i.e. all missing types were assumed to be `int`, so what you defined is equivalent to

```
int error_area(int area_code, int S, ... /* and so on */
{
  ...
```

This is totally different from what you said in the prototype. So the compiler is telling you that your declaration contradicts your definition.

Comment: so does that mean for other type of functions besides int I would need to still define the types when I call the function

Comment: @Thao Nguyen: "Call"? This has nothing to do with any "calls". You *declare* the function (the prototype) and you *define* the function (the actual body). In both cases all types have to be explicitly specified. Moreover, `int` also has to be explicitly specified. Only the outdated versions of C language allowed to omit `int`. Not anymore.

Comment: @AndreyT:  And you'll see those outdated versions in practice as long as people still value backward compatibility.  Sometimes bad decisions, or at least regrettable ones, linger a long, long time.

Comment: @David Thornley: Nobody's arguing with that. However, mixing prototypes with K&R-style definitions (as well as mixing non-prototype declarations with prototyped definitions) requires a bit of skill.

Comment: ah okay I see ..I guess my professor teaching us with a old version of C great. thanks for the help

Comment: @Thao Nguyen: Your original code is incorrect in the "old" version as well as in the "new" version of C. In fact, you are using the "old" compiler, judging by the diagnostic message you got. What I said in my answer is perfectly true for the "old" version of C. I.e. you can omit types in the "old" C, but omitted type means `int` and that conflict with `char` in the prototype you provided. That's what your "old" compiler is telling you.